# Find an element by id and replace its contents with php

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, replace, savechanges

I want to use PHP to search through the contents of a file for an element with a specific id, replace its contents, then save my changes to the file. I'm able to load in the HTML, and save it back out again, but am having trouble with the 'find and replace' (currently trying to use preg_replace).

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
// read in the content
$file = file_get_contents('file.php');

// parse $file, looking for the id.
$replace_with = "id='" . 'myID' . "'>" . $replacement_content . "<";
if ($updated = preg_replace('/id\=\"myID\"\>.*?\</', $replace_with, $file)) {   
    // write the contents of $file back to index.php, and then refresh the page.
    file_put_contents('file.php', $updated);
}
```

However, while it successfully loads in the content and writes it out (I've tested it by writing to a separate file), it appears that $updated doesn't actually change.

Any ideas?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this:

```
$html = new DOMDocument(); 
$html->loadHTMLFile('file.php'); 
$html->getElementById('myId')->nodeValue = 'New value';
$html->saveHTMLFile("foo.html");
```

Comment: Thanks. Would I not be able to save it as a php file this way? There's a possibility it may also be xml files in the future.

Comment: You can, but I don't see the point as the the output will still be HTML.

Comment: It needs to be php for now to be used elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, tried this and it works perfectly, also a lot simpler for me to keep track of!

Answer (score 1):

just thinking why are you escaping "=", it should be `/id=\"myID\"\>.*?\</`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some escaping issues going on ;-)

try this:

```
$replace_with = 'id="myID">' . $replacement_content . '</';
if ($updated = preg_replace('#id="myID">.*?</#Umsi', $replace_with, $file)) {   
    // write the contents of $file back to index.php, and then refresh the page.
    file_put_contents('file.php', $updated);
}
```

Comment: That's the modifiers. U is for ungreedy, m is for multiline, s for including newlines and i for case insensitive. Have a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Is it true that with this solution the id must be at the end of the tag? And if so, is there a solution for elements with id's not matching this requirement?