# Insert HTML into existing HTML file using PHP

Tags: php, html, file

So I wanna insert an html element that I have as a string into an existing HTML file on the server.
So I already have my string, I get a handle on the file using `$handle = fopen("file.php", "rw");` and I want to add the string `$content` that contains the HTML in the existing file after the div element that has the id "`inner_container`".

What is the best way to do this ?

Let me know if you need code. Basically what I wanna do is insert HTML after a certain element that Id find using its id.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350141/find-an-element-by-id-and-replace-its-contents-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this one here :

[How can I use XPath and DOM to replace a node/element in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614434/how-can-i-use-xpath-and-dom-to-replace-a-node-element-in-php)

Answer is all about your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to parse the HTML first (and you don't want to use REGEX for this as I learned in the past -- it may work in many cases, but it's not nearly as clean and friendly as using a DOM parser).

I suggest you use simple_html_dom http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ to parse the HTML of the file first, then add your code to it and save. You can do this with built in functionality of simple_html_dom.